# how to prevent ggplot `geom_ridgeline_gradient` to mess up plot after specifying `group` aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom, phyloseq, ggtree

I want to create a plot that shows a phylogenetic tree on the left side, and and a ridge plot on the right side that visualizes the presence different DNA motifs (short stretches of important sequences), where each sequence is aligned to its corresponding leaf node in the phylogenetic tree. Basically I want to re-create the plot shown [here](https://yulab-smu.top/treedata-book/chapter9.html) (Fig. 9.4), with my own data and using `geom_ridgeline_gradient`.

However, the `group` aesthetic seems to be making problems, as it messes up the correct rendering of the plot.

The problem seems to be part of the `geom_ridgeline_gradient`.
Here is a minimal example of my problem:

```
library(ggridges)
library(ggtree)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

minimal_data1 <- data.table(
  seq = rep("seq1", 20),
  id = rep(1, 20),
  pos = rep(seq(1, 10), 2), 
  height = c(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), # overlapping motifs
  annotation = c(c(NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", "C", "C", "C", NA))
)
minimal_data2 <- data.table(
  seq = rep("seq_2", 10),
  id = rep(2, 10),
  pos = seq(1, 10), 
  height = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
  annotation = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "B", "B", "B", "B", NA, NA)
)
minimal_data3 <- data.table(
  seq = rep("seq_3", 10),
  id = rep(2, 10),
  pos = seq(1, 10), 
  height = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), # sequence without any motifs
  annotation = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
minimal_data <- rbindlist(list(minimal_data1, minimal_data2, minimal_data3))

# this works fine
ggplot(minimal_data, aes(x=pos, y=seq, height=height, fill=annotation)) + 
  geom_ridgeline_gradient(scale=0.3) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(na.translate=FALSE)

# this messes up everything
ggplot(minimal_data, aes(x=pos, y=seq, group=seq, height=height, fill=annotation)) + 
  geom_ridgeline_gradient(scale=0.3) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(na.translate=FALSE)
```

Plotting without specifying `group` gives a perfectly fine plot, but adding `group` messes everything up.
The problem is that I apparently need to specify `group` in order to make the plot compatible with ggtree.

Given that I need to stick with the `group` parameter, **what could be the reason of faulty rendering and how could one fix this?**

Comment: How are you trying to use this with `ggtree`? What are you saying that using `group=` is required?

Comment: `geom_ridgeline_gradient` is described as 'experimental', so that could be a reason as to why it's behaving unexpectedly. If you need to use `group` with `ggtree`, you could add `group=NULL` in the aes definition of `geom_ridgeline_gradient`, or even more appropriately `geom_ridgeline`.